# Android EditText focus on Spinner selection

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

In my Android application, I have several `EditText` controls and spinners (almost 400 controls like that)... when I select a spinner, after selection the focus goes to `EditText` randomly, sometime top most edit text... due to this I have to scroll down and when I choose another spinner value, again focus goes to `EditText`.

Is there any way to avoid this so that the focus stays in the control which is chosen?

Comment: Is this solved?. Please share the solution for this. For me in one device it happens

Answer (score 0):

On your spinner view, try

```
android:nextFocusUp="@id/spinner"
android:nextFocusLeft="@id/spinner"`
```

Comment: This looks more than comment, instead of answer.

Comment: *Try* for me, means that you are not sure that it can help resolve someone's problem. It's like *try this, maybe this will help, maybe not*. Your post has been marked as low quality by system. That is my opinion during review, there are other people also who will check your posts and make final decision.

Comment: Since some dude called my answer as comment, all my answers are comments?

Comment: No. Like I said, that is just **my** opinion in review queue. Yours - this - answer was marked by system as possible low quality, not me. I'm just making review and giving my opinion. Please read this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try android:nextFocusDown="your_second_spinner_id ".You can also try other attribute like nextFocusForward etc.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but I suppose either the first link or a combination of the following ones, will solve your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23235769/2486904
[Spinner does not get focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443212/spinner-did-not-got-focus)
[Adding Focus to a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241698/adding-focus-to-a-spinner)